# Android YouTubePlayer with unauthorized overlay on top of player

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-framelayout

I'm using YouTubePlayer (YouTube api for android) within a Fragment
I am inflating a LinearLayout with the YouTube Player, in this way:

```
fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                    player = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.youTubePlayerContainer, player); 
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

...Where youTubePlayerContainer is the inflated LinearLayout

The player is detected correctly, start playing and in a second stops.
The Log shows the following:

```
YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. 
The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.FrameLayout@4110d1f8. 
YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 484, top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 170..
```

This is my XML:
(No FrameLayout within it)

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/curtain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/withApi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/youTubePlayerContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@color/trans_popUp"
                android:padding="3dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textYouTubeVisor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title..."
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I tried changing the margins without success.
I read the official documentation but without success
Indicates that the FrameLayout that causes the problem is: android.widget.FrameLayout @ 4110d1f8
But with such a reference does not identify which refers

to someone he did this happen?

I appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: The Player is designed so that you can't put anything over the content or the controls.  Since your not including the player in your layout, I can only assume that the layout is coming up over the video, not under it.  Can you see your title... durring play?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Plz let me know, I am stuck here :(

Comment: @Reyjhon I did not get solve this. If I find a solution, I will explain. if you find one, I would appreciate you to tell me. regards

Comment: Did you find any solution for this as I'm also stuck here :(

Comment: It`s not working for debug apk but when i generated signed apk it`s working fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I faced the same problem today, and for me the error in the logs was:

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI﹕ YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView{42686bc8 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1200,675 #7f0a00a0 app:id/video_player}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: -10, top: -10, right: -10, bottom: -10 (these should all be positive).
```

I fixed this by removing the padding in the YouTubePlayerView in the layout. So my layout looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/video_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000" />
```

Comment: Helped me as well. Additional info- the error happened also when scrolling the page, on which the YouTubePlayerView is located. When the YouTubePlayerView becomes invisible (in mt case due to scroll on activity), the video stopped with this error

Comment: Am using frame layout instead of youtube player. Its not working for me

Comment: for signed apk its working without made any changes

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error. 
Although I did the XML changes, I continued to receive the error:

```
 YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.view.View{59fa6ce V.ED..... ........ 0,0-1440,84 #102002f android:id/statusBarBackground}. The view is inside the YouTubePlayerView, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 2308..
```

**After I set the FULLSCREEN, it worked perfect**

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Hope it will help others.

Comment: Yeah helped! :) :D

Answer (score 5):

The problem is only with layout, the `YouTube Player` doesn't permit any view staying over it, neither invisible nor transparent.

In order to make this visible in your device, enable layout bounds in developer option.(warning with `paddings` and `margins`)

Try to comment out others views' code on your layout and test this again please.

Answer (score 2):

The demo code for the Android API uses this layout for the Fragment demo, maybe that can
get ideas going. See this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/playerfragment_text"/>

  <fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
      android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Youtube Player find out some views overlay it. Just remove those view or setVisible(View.GONE) for them.
Please check this link for more information 
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014087/views-overlayed-above-youtubeplayerfragment-or-youtubeplayerview-in-the-layout-h/21692394#21692394)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove any padding attribute in the Video view.

Wrong:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **android:padding="10dp"** />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Right:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/id_base_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
```

1.add fitSystemWindows.
2.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while play video in youtubeplayer

when I Add this line  ...It's Work for me

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```