# Video is playing for a millisecond implemented using youtubeplayer view

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to implement to play youtube video in my app using youtubeplayer view when user clicks on button but its just playing for a millisecond,after that it just stop.App is not crashing but video is also not playing. 
Code for the same is-

```
public class PlayVideo extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

        public static final String API_KEY = "xxxx";
        String videoId;
        String url="http://www.youtube.com/xxx";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            /** attaching layout xml **/
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);

            /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
            YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
            youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
            videoId=getYoutubeVideoId(url);
            Log.e("id",videoId);
            //videoId=getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

            /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
            player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

            /** Start buffering **/
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo(videoId);
            }
        }

        private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
                    Log.e("on","buffer");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPaused() {
                Log.e("on","pause");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaying() {
                Log.e("on","play");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
                Log.e("on","seekto");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopped() {
                Log.e("on","stop");
            }

        };

        private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {
                Log.e("on","ad");
            }


            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
                Log.e("on","loaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                Log.e("on","loading");
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {
                Log.e("on","vidEnd");
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
                Log.e("on","vidStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        public static String getYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl)
         {
         String video_id="";
          if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0 && youtubeUrl.startsWith("http"))
         {

        String expression = "^.*((youtu.be"+ "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*"; // var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
         CharSequence input = youtubeUrl;
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
         if (matcher.matches())
         {
        String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
         if(groupIndex1!=null && groupIndex1.length()==11)
         video_id = groupIndex1;
         }
         }
         return video_id;
         }
    }
```

xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="5dp" />
```

warning in logcat-

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(8722): YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView{41c88550 V.E..... ........ 0,0-480,270 #7f05003d app:id/youtube_player}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: -8, top: -8, right: -8, bottom: -8 (these should all be positive).
```

Comment: Neha, Check your edited xml. have you tried it with that way?

Comment: @pratik-can't send u my code but u may try it just take a button for playing video in one of ur activity n on clicking it pass ur intent to this activity. This is all what i have done,so u may try the code like this.

Comment: @pratik-edited xml is not solving the purpose

Comment: Neha, its ok, let me try dear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014087/views-overlayed-above-youtubeplayerfragment-or-youtubeplayerview-in-the-layout-h/21692394#21692394 visit this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067783/android-youtubeplayer-with-unauthorized-overlay-on-top-of-player

Comment: @pratik-in both links they have suggested not to use any view above youtubeplayer view which was also suggested by u but its not solving my purpose.

Comment: Neha, ya you are right, but issue is perfectly that, you have to check it in your layout. In first link they suggested to use it with fragment then try once with fragment, may be it ll work.

Comment: have you solved this one or not still?

Comment: @pratik-yeah solved it by using fragment.

Comment: Hmmm so issue in layout right? and grt tht u solved it dear.

Comment: Hi @PratikDasa@Anushka i'm getting same issue in my recycle-view..

Comment: @Anushka can help you in this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved by using youtubeplayer fragment rather than youtubeplayer view.Code for the same is-

xml-

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
      android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

java file-

```
public class PlayVideo extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "your api key";
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
String url="your video url";
 String VIDEO_ID;

YouTubePlayerFragment myYouTubePlayerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);
 myYouTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment)getFragmentManager()
   .findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
 myYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
 VIDEO_ID=getYoutubeVideoId(url);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
  YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
 if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
  errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
 } else {
  String errorMessage = String.format(
    "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer (%1$s)",
    errorReason.toString());
  Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
  boolean wasRestored) {
 if (!wasRestored) {
       player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);     
 }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

 if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
  // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
  getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
 }
}

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
 return (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
}
public static String getYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl)
     {
     String video_id="";
      if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0 && youtubeUrl.startsWith("http"))
     {

    String expression = "^.*((youtu.be"+ "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*"; // var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
     CharSequence input = youtubeUrl;
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
     if (matcher.matches())
     {
    String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
     if(groupIndex1!=null && groupIndex1.length()==11)
     video_id = groupIndex1;
     }
     }
     return video_id;
     }
}
```

Add internet permission in your manifest file.