# Youtube api "UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY" error

Tags: android, youtube, fragment

This is my main fragment

```
public class VirtualClassFragment extends Fragment// implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener 
{
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_virtual_class, container, false);
        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment pl = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youTubePlayerFragment);

        pl.initialize("<API_KEY>", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo("nGyqHoKa7yk");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
        return v;
     }
 }
```

and here is my xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youTubePlayerFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am getting youtube video, but after playing it for 1 second, it gives me error of "UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY".
 I have searched a lot and everyone is saying we can not add another view on it, but as you can see there is just fragment in my xml, nothing else.

Comment: yes i am using real key, for security purpose i dint put it here

Comment: Make sure there are no views above the video view, even if it hidden by 1px of another view it might stop working

Comment: as you can see in xml, i am not using anything neither in xml nor in java file

Comment: And in your activity?

Comment: activity just contains slidingmenu, which i am not opening at all

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Nothing in my view hierarchy except the player. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes in my case `NavigationDrawer` was creating the issue.

Comment: I ended up solving this problem by reducing the targetSdkVersion in my app's build.gradle to 19. Not sure why, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of youtube api:

YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY: Playback has been stopped due to a view overlaying the player.
Which can be found in [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason/%20here)
its might also happen by adding padding, margin or other views created by your activity..

I Can also suggest you creating fresh activity and fragment which contains only youtube view and testing it..

Also maby this links will help you understand more of this issue:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067783/android-youtubeplayer-with-unauthorized-overlay-on-top-of-player)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014087/views-overlayed-above-youtubeplayerfragment-or-youtubeplayerview-in-the-layout-h)

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that you have some view above your player. Remove this view and the error will be gone.