# YouTube Video Stop at every 2 Seconds

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

HI I am Using [THIA LIBRARY TO GET ANIMATION LIKE FLIPBOARD APPLICATION](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip)

When I flip one view, I am calling another view which contains a huge Data including **YouTube Video** and I am inflating all these into RecyclerView. Things are working fine but When I am playing YouTube Video , My video getting pause after every 1-2 seconds with this Message in my LogCat.

```
YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.opengl.GLSurfaceView{41ced230 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-720,1230}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 20, top: 628, right: 63, bottom: 244..
```

Answer (score 2):

You may follow this related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067783/android-youtubeplayer-with-unauthorized-overlay-on-top-of-player). Try removing the padding in the `YouTubePlayerView` in the layout.

> ```
> <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
>     android:id="@+id/video_player"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="#000" />
> ```

Youtube Player don't allow any view overlay it. Just using setVisibility(View.GONE) for all view overlay it. [[Source.]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21692394/5832311)