# How can I play a YouTube video through its link in an Android app?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-video-player

I want to add something like a "YouTubePlayer view" to my Android app and play a video in it. There are a lot of tutorials on how to play a video using its id, but none of the ones I found discussed about how to play it using its link.

Here are some of the formats in which a link can be:

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=g-vrec&v=Y1xs_xPb46M';
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Ab25nviakcw#';
url = 'http://youtu.be/Ab25nviakcw';
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ab25nviakcw';
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGL22PTIOAM&feature=g-all-xit';
```

Is it possible to do it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try PIP mode, the same way as WhatsApp does.
Here's another case:
[Play video from youtube in picture-in-picture mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043791/play-video-from-youtube-in-picture-in-picture-mode)

Comment: I'm sorry but playing the video in PIP mode is not what I want here. Isn't there any way I can play a video in a view directly through link?