# How to implement Picture in Picture Webview on IOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I new swift , i want to implement feature picture in picture (PiP) in webview for android , ios . I've found all the posts here and implement some code :

for android (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061449/15311463) It working

for ios not working . I configed BackgourdMode in Xcode . What i am missing ?

```
private var pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController!
let source = """
                    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                        if (e.target.id === 'pip_mobile_btn_img') {
                            window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage('true');
                        }
                    })
                """
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPlayer", sender: self)
        //print("Hello Thinh")
        if #available(iOS 14.2, *) {
          self.pictureInPictureController.canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true
          self.pictureInPictureController.startPictureInPicture()
        }
    }
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
        
        let script = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        webConfiguration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
        webConfiguration.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")
        
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.isOpaque = true
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
        
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: playerURL)!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get or set `allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback` for your wkwebviewconfiguration

```
WKWebViewConfiguration().allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
```

A user can disable Picture in Picture’s automatic invocation in Settings > General > Picture in Picture > Start Pip Automatically. If you think you’ve set up everything correctly and find that your video does not enter PiP when you press the Home button, check this settings.

Comment: all my UI is webview , it suitable for your code ? @Jayesh Patel

Comment: I have edited my answer for that

Comment: then , i can resize webview ? like : 
` if WKWebViewConfiguration().allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback{
// resize webview or some idea ?
}

Comment: WKWebViewConfiguration().allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true

Comment: yes , i know , but my feature is : when press button on webview . my app will PiP (webview resize , i think so) .  `    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPlayer", sender: self)
        print("Hello")
        WKWebViewConfiguration().allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
    }
`