# How to play android youtube player on mute similar to playstore app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want android youtube player to auto-play the video on mute when loaded, something similar to what playstore is recently been doing for a while. I am not able to find any API to be able to mute the player.

Also, I don't understand how the playstore app is displaying an animated equalizer over the player as it is not allowed as per youtube's policy
and will return the error like below

```
YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorised overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.view.View{59fa6ce V.ED..... ........ 0,0-1440,84 #102002f android:id/statusBarBackground}. The view is inside the YouTubePlayerView, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 2308..
```

Although I was able to achieve the overlay with having a SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW or using elevation for my view. I am not sure if this is something which goes against the youtube's policy.

[image]

Comment: Hey! Google is the owner of youtube and play-store. So, they can use it as they want.

Comment: I think this might help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067783/android-youtubeplayer-with-unauthorized-overlay-on-top-of-player
I am sorry if it doesn't.

Comment: You can use VolumeProvider.