# Widget over youtube player on Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm using the youtube API for android, i'm trying to place a button over the player, the problem is every time I try to play a video on the youtube player it stops after one second, i've removed the button and everything works like a charm.
is there a way to solve this? to be able to have any widget over the youtube player? 
Thanks
Adi

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014087/views-overlayed-above-youtubeplayerfragment-or-youtubeplayerview-in-the-layout-h

Comment: Thanks, it's seems that according to Overlay ActionBar Demo given in the answer you can only do it in fullscreen mode.