# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment Show me - This videos is unavailable

Tags: android

**Error**

01-30 16:49:59.180 5634-5882/com.wealthvruddhi.finmo E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.
01-30 16:49:59.198 5634-5634/com.wealthvruddhi.finmo E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
01-30 16:49:59.312 26500-5854/? E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Failed to construct CronetEngine using CronetProvider: App-Packaged-Cronet-Provider, 80.0.3987.9

**java**

public class GuestFinmoIsDifferentFragment extends Fragment implementsYouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

```
public GuestFinmoIsDifferentFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View fragmentYoutubeView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guest_finmo_is_different, container, false);


    YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX youtubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX();
    youtubePlayerFragment.initialize(KEY, this);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.youtube_player_fragment, youtubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    return fragmentYoutubeView;
}


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    if (!b){

        youTubePlayer.loadVideo("https://youtu.be/uaz4yAbR_OA");
    }


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cueVideo` method. It will work, and just pass your videoId.

```
if (!b){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("uaz4yAbR_OA");
    }
```

Comment: And it's pause after every 2 seconds

Comment: In my case working perfect, please check other code. and upvote/accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you for your help

here I am trying lot..but i am not getting sollution

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38772274/4659743
Any overlay to the video player is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different video. I am showing the video in your code above is not available.

```
https://youtu.be/uaz4yAbR_OA
```

You can also try removing all views from being on top of your `YouTubePlayerView`. It's possible that this is returning your error below.

```
E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the Video ID, not the whole URL.

Change this ...

```
youTubePlayer.loadVideo("https://youtu.be/uaz4yAbR_OA");
```

To this ...

```
youTubePlayer.loadVideo("uaz4yAbR_OA");
```