# Android camera preview show only half bottom

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-textureview

I used this library https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel and I have a youtube fragment at top side, a camera preview (inside a fragment) at bottom side.

I want my camera preview show only half bottom part of camera (I don't take pictures, I just preview the bottom part of the front camera is like a mirror)
How do I crop my camera preview? Thank you all the help!

I've tried set SurfaceView height=screenwidth and parentView height=my_height but my top fragment (youtube fragment) was displayed like a SurfaceView

Comment: What do you want exactly first clear that !

Comment: @Cver, please post your current condition which means your XML and screenshot of current state.

Answer (score 0):

set fix height (e.g. 200dp)to `surfaceView` and align it to the bottom of the parent(screen). 
and  set the camera preview size accordingly

```
 Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
 params.setPreviewSize(your_width,your_height);
 camera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: SurfaceView still only shows the center of the camera, not the bottom.

Comment: center of camera??? i could not get you. Do you want to show bottom end of the image only instead of full image? can you show the image of output of your code and the desired output which you want

Comment: I don't take pictures, I just preview the bottom part of the front camera is like a mirror

Comment: Sorry i could not get what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot crop the camera preview image in a SurfaceView.

You can hide the upper half of a SurfaceView by simply overlaying it with some other view (normal XML layout feature). But be careful: SurfaceView does not behave exactly as a "real" view, and it does not always "play by the rules" of view hierarchy. Typically you can overcome these glitches by building the view hierarchy programmatically in `onResume()`.

An alternative is to switch to [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), or use a SurfaceTexture directly and display it in an OpenGL context of your choice. In the latter case, you can partially overlay the camera preview texture with some other OpenGL object, e.g. display decoded video stream in the same OpenGL context.

Comment: I saw this, I have a YoutubeFragment at top side and when I set YoutubeFragment overlaying SurfaceView, my YoutubeFragment displayed like a part of SurfaceView. I also tried with TextureView but both Fragment cannot overlap, the top view was pushed down the bottom view

Comment: *YoutubeFragment displayed like a part of SurfaceView* - can you share a screenshot? This sounds very unusual

Comment: *both Fragment cannot overlap, the top view was pushed down the bottom view* - this may be simply that your XML layout is wrong

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1pw9z youtube screen display as well as a camera preview

Comment: I don't think so, because i use a RelativeLayout as parent view and I don't set any attributes expect id,width,height for view of youtube and camera

Comment: What I see in your screenshot, is that the [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) does not coexist with SurfaceView. This is not unexpected: both views are actually "holes" in the Android view layout system, optimized for hardware rendering. You could try ExoPlayer as an alternative (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014087/views-overlayed-above-youtubeplayerfragment-or-youtubeplayerview-in-the-layout-h)

Comment: Wow, I just recently known ExoPlayer, actually my main application was complicated and if I change, there will be more trouble, I can ask is ExoPlayer can play youtube video and can run inside my fragment? Or should I edit my code if possible?

Comment: I am not an expert in ExoPlayer. You can read their documents.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding enabling `hardwareAccelerated` in `Manifest` solved the problem of preview of `CameraX` coming in half portion although I set `match_parent` as height width of `PreviewView`

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.CameraActivity"
        android:label="@string/camera"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
```