# YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player, The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor ViewPager

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am developing android application using youtube api, my application contain viewPager with 4 pages. each page contain fragments and each fragment contain two fragment; the first one is recyclerView of videos and second one is
Video player appeared when onClick on any item in recyclerView.

but the following problem appeared when Viewing the video on VideoPlayer:
"**YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player, The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor viewPager**"

any one can help to overcome this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some people here in this Stack overflow community resolved this kind of issue in YouTube by removing the padding in the YouTubePlayerView in the layout if you have any.

So it looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
android:id="@+id/video_player"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000" />
```

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014087/views-overlayed-above-youtubeplayerfragment-or-youtubeplayerview-in-the-layout-h/21692394#21692394).